# How to limit display data based on record value using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to limit display data based on record data value.

This is my code :

**models.py**

```
class Subcategory(models.Model):
    subcategory_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Question(models.Model):
    question_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('Subcategory', models.DO_NOTHING, default=None)
    practice_setting = models.ForeignKey('PracticeSetting', models.DO_NOTHING, default=None)
    question = models.TextField()
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PracticeSetting(models.Model):
    practice_setting_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    num_of_question = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class SubcategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Subcategory
        fields = ('subcategory_id',
                  'subcategory')

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_id',
                  'subcategory',
                  'practice_setting',
                  'question',
                  'answer')

class PracticeSettingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PracticeSetting
        fields = ('practice_setting_id',
                  'num_of_question')
```

**view.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def subcategory_list(request):
    # GET list of subcategory
    if request.method == 'GET':
        subcategories = Subcategory.objects.all()
        
        subcategory = request.GET.get('subcategory', None)
        if subcategory is not None:
            subcategories = subcategories.filter(subcategory__icontains=subcategory)
        
        subcategories_serializer = SubcategorySerializer(subcategories, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(subcategories_serializer.data, safe=False)

@api_view(['GET'])
def question_list(request):
    # GET list of question
    if request.method == 'GET':
        questions = Question.objects.all()
    
        subcategory = request.GET.get('subcategory', None)
        if subcategory is not None:
            questions = questions.filter(subcategory__subcategory__icontains=subcategory)
    
        questions_serializer = QuestionSerializer(questions, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(questions_serializer.data, safe=False)

@api_view(['GET'])
def practiceSetting_list(request):
    # GET list of practiceSetting
    if request.method == 'GET':
        practiceSettings = PracticeSetting.objects.all()
        
        practiceSetting = request.GET.get('practiceSetting', None)
        if practiceSetting is not None:
            practiceSettings = practiceSettings.filter(practiceSetting__icontains=practiceSetting)
        
        practiceSettings_serializer = PracticeSettingSerializer(practiceSettings, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(practiceSettings_serializer.data, safe=False)
```

**/api/subcategory**

```
[
  {
     subcategory_id: 1,
     subcategory: "Mathematics"
  },
  {
     subcategory_id: 2,
     subcategory: "History"
  }
]
```

I have 2 subcategory data, Mathematics and History.

**/api/questions?subcategory=Mathematics**

```
[
  {
     question_id: 1,
     subcategory: 1,
     practice_setting : 1,
     question: "10 + 10 = ?",
     answer: "20"
  },
  {
     question_id: 2,
     subcategory: 1,
     practice_setting : 1,
     question: "20 + 20 = ?",
     answer: "40"
  },
  {
     question_id: 3,
     subcategory: 1,
     practice_setting : 1,
     question: "30 + 30 = ?",
     answer: "60"
  },
  {
     question_id: 4,
     subcategory: 1,
     practice_setting : 1,
     question: "40 + 40 = ?",
     answer: "80"
  },
  {
     question_id: 5,
     subcategory: 1,
     practice_setting : 1,
     question: "50 + 50 = ?",
     answer: "100"
  },
  {
     question_id: 6,
     subcategory: 1,
     practice_setting : 1,
     question: "60 + 60 = ?",
     answer: "120"
  }
]
```

On the list of mathematics questions I have 6 questions

**/api/practice-setting**

```
[
  {
    practice_setting_id: 1,
    num_of_question: 3
  },
  {
    practice_setting_id: 2,
    num_of_question: 5
  }
]
```

In the practice settings list I have 2 data, one with 3 numbers of questions and the other with 5 numbers of questions.

My question,
how to limit display data based on number of questions in **/api/practice-setting**?

For example `num_of_question: 3` so the **/api/questions?subcategory=Mathematics** only displays 3 questions and for example if the value is changed to 4 then it will display 4 questions.

I have no idea to do that,
I'm still a beginner and need a lot of guidance please help.

Comment: which 3 questions ? first 3 or last 3 ?

Comment: this first 3 questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first 3 questions from a query set you can use array slicing like this

```py
questions = questions.filter(subcategory__subcategory__icontains=subcategory)[:3] 
 # get the first 3 items
```

Now since you need to also retrieve the data, you might need to make another query to get the `num_of_questions` field first like

```py
first_question = questions.filter(subcategory__subcategory__icontains=subcategory)[1].get()  # get the first item
num_of_questions = first_question.practice_setting.num_of_question  # get the num_of_question field associated with the first question retrieved
questions = questions.filter(subcategory__subcategory__icontains=subcategory)[:num_of_questions]  # get the first n items where n = num_of_questions
```

> The `.get()` here is used to retrieve he object itself and not just the query set, you can also use the `.first()` function instead of the slice + get like

```
first_question = questions.filter(subcategory__subcategory__icontains=subcategory).first()  # get the first item
```

Note that I'm relying on getting the `practice_setting` object associated with the first question under that subcategory, you might have other preferences but this is just an example that you can modify as you need